# QuickSort in C library

Tags: c, quicksort

### The Second Param of qsort

Now I want to sort a set of points by x.Following is my code:

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} point;

int cmpfunc( const void * a, const void * b){
    point *point1 = (point *)(a);
    point *point2 = (point *)(b);

    if(point1->x < point2->x){
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(){

    point *points = (point *)malloc(sizeof(point)*3);
    points[0].x = 1;
    points[0].y = 2;

    points[1].x = 0;
    points[1].y = 4;

    points[2].x = 4;
    points[2].y = 3;

    qsort(points,2,(sizeof(points[0])),cmpfunc);

    int i=0;
    while (i<3){
        printf("x=%d",points[i].x);
        printf("y=%d\n",points[i].y);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please notice **qsort(points,2,(sizeof(points[0])),cmpfunc);**

The result is correct when I pass the second param value `2` not `3`.What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Your comparison function is broken, it never returns greater than zero.

Comment: Thanks ver much@unwind

Comment: Another possible problem: you are sorting 2 elements of 3, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort on the x axis, you need something like:

```
static void cmpfunc(const void *a, const void *b)
{
  const point *pa = a, *pb = b;
  return pa->x < pb->x ? -1 : pa->x > pb->x;
}
```

It must return less than, equal to, or greater than zero. [See the manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) for more.

Oh, and you really shouldn't "drop const" like that, for no reason, and of course you never need to cast from `void *` to a pointer to `struct` like we have here. Keep it simple, and learn these things so you don't feel a need to "throw in a cast for good measure".